# Menu items break on Chrome/Safari (Mac) but not on Firefox and Chrome for Win

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I ran into a weird situation when building the [following menu](http://dev.tiagoduarte.com/unitedhosting/).
On Chrome/Safari (Mac) the last menu item breaks when I add `padding-left: 7px;` to the `<ul>`  however that's the only way I was able to display the menu centered on Firefox and Chrome for Windows.

I tried centering the menu with `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` but that didn't work as well. I think I've ran out of possible solutions.

Looking forward to your replies,

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because Chrome is rendering the fonts slightly differently and there will be a few pixels difference (about 4 or 5px over the screen width in this case).

Here's a little trick I picked up a while ago to center the nav without padding and such:

```
.site-header .site-nav ul {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.site-header .site-nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left; }
```

Notice there's no other margins or padding on the ul apart from the auto left and right.
You'll also need to clear the ul with a clearfix because the li's are now floated.

Or if you don't like using `display:table` you can do the same with `display:inline-block` on the ul, then set `text-align:center` on the `.site-nav`

Comment: I tried your solution and it didn't center the menu. However, it caused the fonts to render the same on all the browsers so with some extra padding on the left side this is now fixed and working properly! Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take the padding-left down to 6px and on the li take the 23px down to 22 and it should fix the problem and center it.

Comment: This doesn't leave any room for browser rendering differences. Phones and tablets may render differently again. The ul should not be measured exactly to the pixel.

Comment: That fixes the problem on Chrome but on Firefox this happens to the right side of the the menu: http://cl.ly/QqDU

Answer (score 0):

This problem was there because of the webfont that was used. Using `display:table` on the menu item also worked for me.

But I went for an other solution instead: Setting the `font-family` to `empty` on the menu element. And re-setting the `font-family` on the li element, fixed this problem.

More info can be found here: https://matthewlein.com/articles/inline-block-fix